# Changing programming language after 10 years. How to convince the companies to hire me as a programmer?

Tags: job-change, india

I have worked with C++ for quite some time. I have worked with Qt also. Meanwhile I also worked with Python. I am a jack of all currently.

I have now started learning MEAN stack. I am excited about it.

How do I apply for jobs of MEAN stack requiring 3-5 years of experience - in future?

In the resume I will have to mention the total work experience of 10 years. Problem is that I feel companies will simply throw my resume after looking at the number of years of experience.

***I am ready to work for a different pay scale. How do I mention this in resume without sounding desperate?***

Country: India

Comment: most job ads ask for relevant experience correct?

Comment: You mean it really doesn't matter how much "overall" experience a person has? @user180146

Comment: Does your job leave you enough spare time to work on personal projects?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, it does.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl that is indeed partly what I mean. Youre previous workexperience can be relevant, partly relevant or not relevant at all (take the extreme case, you are applying as a software engineer and have experience as a policeofficer, that would not be really relevant)

Comment: I think you are worrying to much about selling yourself short by preemptively lowering your salary requirements. React to opportunities as they arise and be flexible in negotiation, but not communicate from the get-go that you are "not worth it". It's counter-intuitive, I know. Thanks, I am in a similar situation right now and it helped me reflect on my own approach.

Comment: Do you have client/server/web experience already? If so, that's what you want to emphasize in your resume.

Comment: Show stuff.  Build a portefolio in a visible place.  Source code on github or similar, and result in the cloud.  If you use some of your own software at home, consider polishing that up into a showcase as this is something you care about.  For an experienced programmer, the way such a project looks is very telling about how you think and code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thank you for useful input.

Answer (score 3):

> I am ready to work for a different pay scale. How do I mention this in resume without sounding desperate?

Do not mention this. It not only robs you of all negotiation strength, but also makes you look like a poor candidate by you are communicating that you are asking for a position that you don't deserve.

Reserve the flexibility for future negotiations. Let it be the interviewers' concern if they want to work with you or not, and don't let self-doubt get into the way.

I also recommend looking into articles and material about negotiation basics. With the right strategy you may get a great job and higher salary than you value yourself. Negotiation involves two parties. Undervaluing yourself can only work in your disfavor, as counter-intuitive as this may sound.

Make sure you are appropriately familiar with the technology that you want to work with professionally, and go from there. Your self-assessment may be very different to the overall assessment of potential employers, including your past experience, since you are zooming in on a single limiting factor, but the interviewers may look at a broader spectrum of what constitutes suitable candidates.

We are our own worst enemies.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody will know exactly what you did before. You will of course need to understand the language very well in your spare time. Stackoverflow would be a good resource.

On your CV, simply state MEAN is one of your technology skills. It's not a lie. As long as you understand it well enough and able to pass technical tests, there won't be a problem.

Comment: thanks- you gave me hope.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to prove to companies that you can work with the technology you claim to know but haven't used professionally yet is by creating an own personal project and showing it to them or by contributing to an open source project.

The nice thing about the MEAN stack is that it is free software and designed for public web applications. So you could create one and mention the URL in your application.

When a job posting requests "3-5 years of experience", then don't feel discouraged from applying if you don't have that much experience on paper. Requirements for job postings are wish lists. Many companies will hire people who do not fulfill all of them, but can prove in other ways that they are capable of doing the things they need. Or if they have other qualifications which speak for them (like 10 years of experience in very similar skills).

You can mention your desired salary in your application. Some companies will even expect that. If you choose to do that, provide **a concrete number** of your expected gross salary per year. Do not quantify it by calling it "low" or "below market rate" or anything. That will only make you seem desperate. Feel free to lowball if you think you need to (but do you really? Do not underestmate your market-worth!). But keep in mind that this will be the upper limit to what they are going to offer you. They will only try to haggle you lower. They won't offer you a single rupee more than you stated, and any future negotiations for a raise will use your initial salary as a baseline.

Comment: What can be written in the resume to ensure them that I can work with lower pay?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl "I will work for less money" is something you should **never** write in a resume. It is only going to harm you when you negotiate your salary.

Comment: I don't want them to throw away my resume because of salary concerns. What is the way to ensure that?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I updated the answer.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl the provide "minimal salary" on your cv. It will weaken your position in negotiations, but then getting paid less doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: `Provide a concrete number of your expected gross salary per year` Bad negotiation strategy and should be avoided whenever possible. It robs you of all negotiation strength, among other problems.

Comment: @ig-dev I believe I explained that this is the case and should only be done if OP believes they have to compete with the other applicants by wanting less salary.

Answer (score 0):

The A in MEAN stands for Angular, but Angular is not as popular now as it once was. Plus, there are two different flavors of it.

If I were going to learn something new with a steep learning curve, I would learn React instead. It's more current. I guess that would make it MARN.

Answer (score -1):

If can't create your personal project, then look for open-source projects and contribute to them (in github, etc.).

You can show how your work made valuable contributions in real software.

Warning: you will have to invest some time in researching the culture of the project, what contributions they will value more, their coding style, reading the forum and mailing list, meeting their devs on chat, etc.

This could be a lot slower then having your own project with your own rules, where you only need to agree with yourself.

If you put your own personal project on github, etc, you can show them on your resume. You can say you are passionate about the language.

Comment: Passionate is a strong word.  These are all in all just tools.